# IIS 8 publish difficulties while browse

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I have publish my code in **IIS 8** but while browsing it give me only this files list. IIS display only this list while browse:

[image]

My default application pool:

> .NET framework version is v2.0 classic

but i change it on:

> .NET framework version v4.0 classic and Integrated

both

but iis display same list every time.

My published code is on MVC 4.

Comment: Image that you have provided in link is not opening, please provide the alternative link or paste it here only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have not defined the default controller for your website.

To set the default controller on your website, you need to set below code in **RouteConfig.cs** in **App_Start** folder.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
 routes.MapRoute(
 name: "Default",
 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HomeLogin", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

**Alternative:**

1) Right click on your project solution

2) Select Property

3) Select Web option and then Select Specific Page (Controller/View) and then set your home/start page.